# Calculating the number of open triangles in a networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a networkx graph G, say for example

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,.1)
```

I would like to count in an efficient way to the number of open triples, that is, the frequency of the pattern: A is connected to B, B is connected to C but A and B are not connected.

Is there a clever way to exploit a built in function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can compute the distance matrix `(1 if i->j, else 0)` of `G`, you can square it and for each non-diagonal entry, check if `a[i,j]` is different from `a[j,i]`.